# Javascript : Maintain the unicode after json.parser(json)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, unicode, mongodb-query

I have a JSON object as below

```
var a = {"1.jpg":aaa}
```

In order to insert the JSON object into MongoDB I tried converting the '.' to its corresponding Unicode by the following steps.

```
var b = JSON. stringify(a);
b.replace(".","\\uFF0E")
var c = JSON.parse(b);
```

On parsing the JSON 'b' the Unicode again changes to '.' which is not accepted in MongoDB. Is there any way to maintain the Unicode instead of '.'?

Comment: That should be `"\\uFF0E"`. That is, it should be a zero, not an O.

Comment: That was a typo. Sorry!

Comment: A `.` *after* the object literal…? What's that supposed to signify excatly?

Comment: A typo again! Sorry guys. I am asking about the dot in Object key

Comment: How exactly does Mongo "not accept" that? How are you inserting it into the database? Sounds like an XY problem.